# Two form values are not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, devise

I have this signup for with devise:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

  <%= f.fields_for :profile, resource.build_profile do |t| %>
     <div class ="field">
        <%= t.label :type, "Are you an artist or listener?" %><br />
        <div>Artist: <%= t.radio_button :type, "Profile::Artist", :id => "artist_button" %></div>
        <div>Listener: <%= t.radio_button :type, "Profile::Listener", :id => "listener_button" %></div>
      </div>
  <% end %>

  <p class="before"><%= f.submit "Sign up", :id => "new_user_submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Then I have some JQuery that inserts a field dynamically:

```
$("#artist_button").click(function() {
        if ($('input#user_name').parent().hasClass('field')){
            $('input#user_name').parent().remove();
        }
        $(".before").before('<div class="field"><label for="user_name">Artist or Band/Group Name</label><br><input id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text"></div>');
    });
```

However, the `type` attribute that is nested in the user form and the `name` attribute that is inserted dynamically are not being saved to the database. The values are being entered as null.

Why is this? How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

The name attribute was not `attr_accessible` and that was causing it to not be saved to the db. However, the type attribute, which is nested inside the user form, is `attr_accessible` but is still not being saved to the db.

Comment: What's actually submitted? What do you see in params in your development log?

Comment: it's in the params but I don't think they are `attr_accessible`... would type go in the profile model?

Comment: Like @apneadiving, I strongly suspect you haven't marked these attributes as attr_accessible. Devise by default protects all the attributes on your user model, so you need to make them accessible.

Comment: oh, so name wasn't attr_accessible, and making it so fixed that... but type was and still is attr_accessible but it's not being saved to the db... might have something to do with nested forms combined with devise

Comment: Do you have accepts_attributes_for :profile ?

Comment: I have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile`... should I take out the `nested`?

Comment: No, it was my typo. What do you see in delelopment logs in the params hash? Is it submitted?

Comment: yeah, these are my params: `Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign up", "authenticity_token"=>"Y5MwT3/vQIbyFLZN3PWLW/GNSYAOhEDDkIer02lfhbk=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"name"=>"Rapper", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "profile_attributes"=>{"type"=>"Profile::Artist"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"efe@eff.com"}}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protec`

Comment: Oh, just noticed this: `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: profile_attributes`

Comment: ok needed to make it attr_accessible from the user model :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting in your User Model:

```
attr_accessible :profiles_attributes
```

along with the rest of devises `attr_accessible(email,remeber_me,etc)` , do not delete what you have!

Answer (score 1):

"type" is a "magic" ActiveRecord column name used for single table inheritance which means that you just got hit by convention-over-configuration. You need to rename your "type" column to something else - I usually use "kind" as a column name.

Answer (score 0):

Is `type` an association? If so, you'd have to add `:type_id` to `attr_accessible`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

in your User model?